# what is the safe/secure way to execute commands from website?

Tags: sudo, php, command, services

I'm working on a website from which some services are generated and need to be placed on the system folder, and those services might also need to start/stop using the systemctl command.

Both commands of placing the service in the system folder and running the systemctl require the use of sudo, what is the safe/secure way to execute such commands from the website without exposing the root password.

Comment: Have you considered shell_exec? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I use `exec(echo mypass | sudo -S -k mycommand)` which does the job too. My concern is about the exposed password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to configure sudo in such a way that those particular commands do not need a password for your webserver user. See `man sudoers` for details. Wrap the commands in shell scripts if necessary, then allow root execution for the shell scripts in `sudoers`.

From your description, it looks like the commands don't need parameters (just a fixed number of services that need to be started or stopped). If they do, then triple check your parameter validation - if you make a mistake there, then that's the way to get root access to your system, password or no password.

Comment: Thank you! I will read the man sudoers details.